# Resources to learn about banking and financial services industry

Tags: finance, banking

Can you recommend resources to learn about how the banks and modern financial system work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to study finance and banking from an economic perspective then common introductory texts are

- Exchange Rates and International Finance from Copeland
- Financial Markets and Institutions from Mishkin
- Money, Banking and Financial Markets from  Cecchetti & Schoenholtz

Depending on whether you are interested in macro or micro perspective you will want to build upon the above with

- The microeconomics of banking from Freiax
- Intermediate Financial Theory form Danthine, Jean-Pierre
- International Macroeconomics and Finance: Theory and Empirical Methods by Nelson C. Mark

The above-mentioned three intermediate/graduate  books also presuppose some knowledge of econometrics, microeconomics and mathematics so you might want to also first study that before delving into these.